# Extract particular values from the output in shell script

Tags: shell-script, sed, grep

I have output, like the following, from postgres database

```
datname | size ---- template1 | 6314 kB template0 | 6201 kB postgres | 7938 kB misago |
6370 kB (4 rows)
```

I want only these 6314, 6201, and 7938 values from output.
How can I do this?

awk, grep or sed are preferable.

Comment: What is the SQL query?

Comment: SELECT pg_database.datname,pg_database_size(pg_database.datname) AS size FROM pg_database;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the output of the database query in `db.out`:

```
grep -oE '[0-9]+ kB' db.out
```

This will produce

```
6314 kB
6201 kB
7938 kB
6370 kB
```

Then strip off the `␣kB` and delete the last line:

```
$ grep -oE '[0-9]+ kB' db.out | sed -e 's/ kB//' -e '$d'
6314
6201
7938
```

If you want this on one line, with three numbers on each line, pass it through `paste`:

```
$ grep -oE '[0-9]+ kB' db.out | sed -e 's/ kB//' -e '$d' | paste - - -
6314    6201    7938
```

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

Sample `testfile` contents:

```
datname | size ---- template1 | 6314 kB template0 | 6201 kB postgres | 7938 kB misago | 6370 kB
datname | size ---- template1 | 3000 kB template0 | 3001 kB postgres | 3002 kB misago | 6370 kB
datname | size ---- template1 | 4014 kB template0 | 4001 kB postgres | 4002 kB misago | 6370 kB
```

---

```
awk -F' *\\| *' '{ for(i=3;i<=5;i++) 
        printf "%s%s",substr($i,1,index($i," ")-1),(i==5? ORS:OFS) }' OFS=',' testfile
```

The output:

```
6314,6201,7938
3000,3001,3002
4014,4001,4002
```

**----------**

In case if the file has a fixed format (there wouldn't be any whitespaces within `template` fields) - use simple ***cut*** approach:

```
cut -d' ' --output-delimiter=',' -f7,11,15 <testfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while read -r i; do
  <<< "${i}" \
  grep -P -o -e '(?<= )([0-9]*?)(?= )' |
  cut -d $'\n' -f 1-3 --output-delimiter=' '
done < 'file'
```

As an one-liner:

```
while read -r i; do <<< "${i}" grep -P -o -e '(?<= )([0-9]*?)(?= )' | cut -d $'\n' -f 1-3 --output-delimiter=' '; done < 'file'
```

Output:

```
6314 6201 7938
```

Change the output delimiter if you want.